# Finding the volume of a $\mathbb R^3$ triangle

Tags: geometry, volume

I have a triangle $ABC$ defined  with the points $A=(2.4,-5.4,6)$, $B=(0,1.1,3.2)$, $C=(-7.6,3,0)$

And I'm asked to find the volume of the solid of $\mathbb R^3$ given by the points between the plane that is made by the points of the triangle and the plaze ${z=0}$ (The same points of the triangle with all the $z=0$)

I think I should use integrals but I don't know from which regions to do the triple integration.

Comment: The polyhedron you have is a truncated right-triangular prism and its volume is the average of the 3 heights times the area of the triangular base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a triangle with vertices $A,B,C$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be obtained using the cross product: $$\mathrm{Surface}=\frac12 \|\overrightarrow{AB}\times \overrightarrow{AC}\|.$$

**The following doesn't give the volume of the region in the question as noticed by @achillehui**

Also, the volume of a tetrahedron defined by four points $A,B,C,D$, can be computed using $$\mathrm{Volume}=\frac16 |\det(\overrightarrow{AB},\overrightarrow{AC},\overrightarrow{AD})|.$$

**Edit**

Assume that $A',B',C'=C$ are the vertices of the triangle on the plane $z=0.$ Then, we can decompose the figure in two tetrahedrons: one with vertices $A',A,B',C$ and the other with vertices $A,B,B',C.$ Using the formula above one gets the volume.

Comment: Up to my understanding, the polyhedron at hand is a truncated right-triangular prism, not a tetrahedron.

Comment: @achillehui You are right. I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @achillehui I have edited the answer. I think that the figure can be decomposed into two tetrahedrons.

Comment: Yes, the figure can be decomposed into two tetrahedron. In fact, the volume of tetrahedron $ABB'C$ is equal to that of $A'BB'C$ by "shifting" the volume vertically downwards. There is a name for this sort of move which preserve volume but I can't remember the name and locate a reference...

Answer (score 1):

First, write down the inequalities that define the triangle. This is the region you'll be integrating across.

Second, compute the function that tells you how far a point, $(x,y,z)$ is from the plane $z=0$. This will be the function you integrate.

Third, put these two together and try computing the integral.

Comment: Hi, I was already trying to find out the inequalities for example $-7.6<x<2.4$ for the first integral but I am getting messed up and I don't know very well how to follow your steps.

Comment: @CescAguirre why don't you edit your post with details such as what you've tried so that I can give more specific advice. It's hard to give advice without solving the problem if you don't communicate what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

The volume is the absolute value of $\frac{6+3.2+0}3·
\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
2.4&-5.4&1\\
0&1.1&1\\
-7.6&3&1
\end{vmatrix}}2$ .

The first fraction is the effective altitude of the prism which will be used as one of the factors in the volume calculation. The second fraction is the area of the base.